# How to detect closed area on picturebox c#

Tags: c#, paint

I create a simple paint application. I have a picture box and I draw line,rectangle,ellipse,... over it.But I dont khow how can I detect a closed area like ellipse on mouse clicked position that fill it with specified color.(i.e I want to simulate Fill with color button in paint).
Can anybody help me?

Thanks

Comment: This can only be a problem if you somehow forgot that an entity is a line or ellipse.  Keep track of shapes, don't just draw pixels.  Now it is simple, you know that you can't fill a line.  And hit-testing becomes simple.  GraphicsPath is a convenient helper class.

Comment: How can I track shapes? Maybe there are many ellipse and rectangle and ... on picture box. I want just that shape I click on it's area fill my color.(sorry for my bad English)

Answer (score 0):

I click on it's area fill my color.@Raha, you can use the AForge library to fill color in the pointed region on shapes of picture box control and PointedMeanFloodFill class.
[link to code:](http://www.aforgenet.com/framework/docs/html/7208f74e-7e5c-1abf-467a-c86083859721.htm)